# how to use same @keyframes and @property twice for more than 1 div?

Tags: html, css, css-variables, css-counter

as you see in this simple css counter, https://codepen.io/bgbos/pen/pobZvwJ we have 4 div's each of them has a different initial value which must be appear at the end of animation but it don't , it all stop at one value

and this is the original one with just on value working good , CSS & HTML

```css
@property --num {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 984;
  inherits: false;
}

#twitter {
  animation: counter 3.9s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count:1;
  counter-reset: num var(--num);
  
  
}
#twitter::before {
  content: counter(num);
}

@keyframes counter {
  from {
    --num: 0;
  }
  to {
    --num: 100;
  }
}



@property --num {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 402;
  inherits: false;
}

#instagram {
  animation: counter 3.9s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count:1;
  counter-reset: num var(--num);
  
  
}
#instagram::before {
  content: counter(num);
}


@property --num {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 254;
  inherits: false;
}

#facebook {
  animation: counter 3.9s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count:1;
  counter-reset: num var(--num);
  
  
}
#facebook::before {
  content: counter(num);
}



@property --num {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 610;
  inherits: false;
}

#youtube {
  animation: counter 3.9s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count:1;
  counter-reset: num var(--num);
  
  
}
#youtube::before {
  content: counter(num);
}
```

```html
<div id="twitter" ></div>
<div id="instagram" ></div>
<div id="facebook" ></div>
<div id="youtube" ></div>
```

https://codepen.io/CarterLi/pen/NWNJvPE
that i was trying to edit .

sorry if there are mistakes , just beginner . appreciate your help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value need to be inside the element and your code can be simplified like below:

```css
#twitter,
#instagram,
#facebook,
#youtube{
  animation: counter 3.9s  ease-in-out;
  counter-reset: num var(--num);
}

#twitter::before,
#instagram::before,
#facebook::before,
#youtube::before{
  content: counter(num);
}

#twitter { --num:984; }
#instagram { --num:402; }
#facebook { --num:254; }
#youtube { --num:610; }

@property --num {
  syntax: "<integer>";
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: false;
}

@keyframes counter {
  from {
    --num: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="twitter" ></div>
<div id="instagram" ></div>
<div id="facebook" ></div>
<div id="youtube" ></div>
```

Comment: really amazing Thanks , How can we keep that same feature in original that's it count from 0 to 100 then jump to the final value ?

Comment: @Sulay add `to {--num:100}` inside the animation